# What is d3.geo.pipeline?

Tags: d3.js, pipeline, geography

If you follow Mike Bostock's bl.ocks, you know for the last 8 months d3.geo.pipeline() has been a frequent component to his projects.

But what's it do?

You see him set pipelines up like this:

```
var sketch = d3.geo.pipeline()
      .source(d3.geo.jsonSource)
      .pipe(resample, .020)
      .pipe(jitter, .004)
      .pipe(smooth, .005)
      .sink(d3.geo.jsonSink);
```

[via](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/e2a20d86124693ef0f93)

There is no documentation in the [d3.geo wiki.](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections)

Some beautified JS in the unreleased D3 used in the code example reveals this function:

```
lo.geo.pipeline = function() {
        var n = [];
        return {
            source: function() {
                return n[0] = arguments, this
            },
            pipe: function() {
                return n.push(arguments), this
            },
            sink: function() {
                for (var t, e = arguments[0].apply(null, [].slice.call(arguments, 1)), r = e; t = n.pop();) {
                    var u = [].slice.call(t, 1);
                    u.push(e), e = t[0].apply(null, u)
                }
                return function() {
                    return e.apply(this, arguments), r.value && r.value()
                }
            }
        }
```

It also appears in these bl.ocks:

- [Back-facing Hemisphere](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/721f6275d7471defd12d)
- [Multiple rotations](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1de35c45f8718c678712)
- [Satellite](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/e48a00d4db5c3b042145)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `d3.js`, but I looked at its source code and found that this feature is located in branch `graphics-pipeline`.

For example you can find related code here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/commit/a3f2adab7f85e2a0c82288ead88c1e484c9e3ea3

---

Small code snippet to illustrate how it works:

```js
var pipeline = function () {
    var pipes = [];
    return {
        source: function () {
            pipes[0] = arguments;
            return this;
        },
        pipe: function () {
            pipes.push(arguments);
            return this;
        },
        sink: function () {
            var sink = arguments[0].apply(null, [].slice.call(arguments, 1)),
                pipe;

            while (pipe = pipes.pop()) {
                var args = [].slice.call(pipe, 1);
                args.push(sink);
                sink = pipe[0].apply(null, args);
            }

            return sink;
        }
    };
};

var log = document.getElementById('log');

function f() {
    var argsAsString = Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ', ');
    var resultName = 'r' + f.callCounter++;

    log.innerHTML += resultName + ' = f(' + argsAsString + ')<br>';

    return resultName;
}

f.callCounter = 1;

pipeline().
    source(f, 'a', 1).
    pipe(f, 'b', 2).
    pipe(f, 'c', 3).
    sink(f, 'd', 4);
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

Few comments about this feature:

1. Methods `source` and `pipe` work with the same private property `pipes`. The difference only is that `source` set initial value for `pipes` (`pipes[0]`), when each call to `pipe` pushes new pipe into collection.
2. Previous fact gives us knowledge about `d3.geo.jsonSource` internal structure. It should be similar to arguments passed to `pipe`: first argument is something callable (function), rest of arguments - parameters.
3. Assume that `arguments = [f, a, b, c]`. Then JavaScript pattern `arguments[0].apply(null, [].slice.call(arguments, 1))` means: `f(a, b, c)`. You can see several places of its usage in `sink` implementation.

---

Regarding practical usage.

We can use it if we need to "chain" (or "pipe") data processing. For example if we have such code:

```
function f(a, b, previousResult) 
{
    return a * b + (previousResult || 0);
}

var p = pipeline().
    source(f, 1, 1).
    pipe(f, 2, 10).
    pipe(f, 3, 100).
    sink(f, 4, 1000);
```

Then the result (value of `p`) will be `4321`.

In this particular case we need to clarify what is `d3.geo.jsonSink` and `d3.geo.jsonSource`, but I hope that I helped you to see the meaning of `pipeline` function.

Comment: I did post that feature's code in the question, but the source link is helpful

Comment: @Incodeveritas, I added few comments regarding this feature.

Comment: @Incodeveritas, I updated my answer once again - maybe now it's more useful.